# ORing the 'where' clause values when using the 'extra' method of the ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

**TLDR** When using the [`where` parameter of the `extra` method of django's queryset api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) you can insert custom SQL that will be `AND`ed to your query. I've got a situation where I need that values `OR`ed with the reset of the query. Is there support for this?

---

I've got a *large* table that has a M2M relationship with another table

```
class BookName:
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True)
    other_names = models.ManyToManyField(OtherName)

class OtherBookName:
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True)
```

I want to query books that have a full name or alternative name from a list.

Using `Q()` naturally slows things down considerably.

My solution is to query `OtherBookName` first for rows that have names in my list and return those pks (which is quick as it's indexed). I then manually include the M2M table between the two models and add a `where` clause that should also pull out `BookName` instance which match on the table.

```
test_names = ["Foo", "Bar",]
other_ids = OtherBookName.objects.filter(name__in=test_names).values_list("id", flat=True)
queryset = self\
            .filter(Q(name__in=test_names)) \
            .extra(
                where=[
                    "bookname_id = app_bookname.id",
                    "booknameotherbookname_id IN (%s)" 
                        % ",".join([str(id) for id in other_ids]),
                ],
                tables=["app_bookname_otherbookname",]) \
            .distinct()
```

This is very close to working except that my where claus is `AND`ed to the query when I would like to `OR` it.

Comment: Can you please check your code again which you posted. `models.ManyToManyField(OtherNames)` did you mean `OtherBookNames` as a relationship here?

Comment: Also `OtherBookNames.objects.filter(name__in=names)` `OtherBookNames` table does not have field `name` it has `names`

Comment: Sorry - you're right, the variables were incorrect

Comment: Sorry I am confused a bit. Do you want Inner `where` clauses in extra to be `OR`, or the whole `where` clause to be `OR` with outer query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
names = ["Foo", "Bar",]
other_ids = OtherBookName.objects.filter(name__in=names).values_list("id", flat=True)
where_clause = "bookname_id = app_bookname.id AND (name IN (%s)" \
                % ",".join(names) + " OR booknameotherbookname_id IN (%s))" \
                % ",".join([str(id) for id in other_ids])
queryset = self\
            .extra(
                where=[where_clause],
                tables=["app_booknames_otherbookname",]) \
            .distinct()
```